# Identify hierarchy in Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, nested-loops, hierarchical-data

Is there a way to identify hierarchies given a set of node relations?

```
--input/existing table
select 'W' as edition, 'X' as new_edition
union
select 'Y' as edition, 'Z' as new_edition
union 
select 'Z' as edition, null as new_edition
union
select 'X' as edition, 'Y' as new_edition;

--expected output
select 'W' as all_editions, 'Z' as latest_edition, 3 as level
union
select 'X' as all_editions, 'Z' as latest_edition, 2 as level
union
select 'Y' as all_editions, 'Z' as latest_edition, 1 as level
union
select 'Z' as all_editions, 'Z' as latest_edition, 0 as level;
```

Great if the levels can be dynamically identified, however the max levels we will have is 10. 
This should cover edge cases when there could be 2 new editions X, X2 linked to W

Comment: I think redshift does not implement recursive CTEs. Does it?

Comment: And what result set do you want the query to produce?  Why do you specify 10 levels and then provide an example edge case that is much simpler?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not worried about the edge cases and the specific levels. I already posted the expected output.

Comment: With recursive CTEs this query is pretty simple. Without recursive CTEs this query *can be done* but will end up a monstruosity.

Comment: @TheImpaler how is this solved using recursive CTE? can you paste the solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I have a basic version of the query that doesn't use a CTE. It doesn't look as bad as I thought.

Here it is for a 6-level hierachy:

```
select
  e1,
  coalesce(e6, e5, e4, e3, e2, e1) as latest_edition,
  case when e2 is null then 0
       when e3 is null then 1
       when e4 is null then 2
       when e5 is null then 3
       when e6 is null then 4
       else 5
  end as level
from (
  select
    t1.edition as e1, t2.edition as e2, t3.edition as e3, 
    t4.edition as e4, t5.edition as e5, t6.edition as e6
  from my_table t1
  left join my_table t2 on t2.edition = t1.new_edition
  left join my_table t3 on t3.edition = t2.new_edition
  left join my_table t4 on t4.edition = t3.new_edition
  left join my_table t5 on t5.edition = t4.new_edition
  left join my_table t6 on t6.edition = t5.new_edition
) x
```

Comment: this solves my problem and covers the edge case..you're a genius! thanks a ton